# Pass parameters to a controller from the View by using ajax and controller pass the new eloquent to the view

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, eloquent

This is how my Controller and View work

Controller

```
class DayhomeController extend Controller{
public function index(){
 $Dataset = Modal::all();
 return view('DayHome')->with('DataSet',$DataSet)
}
```

View

```
 <div class="container" id="container1">
   <input type="date" id="datepicker" name="datepicker" value="<?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?>"
  </div>
@for ($i = 0; $i < count($DataSet); $i++)
<div class="container" id="container2">
    <div> {{$DataSet[$i]->name}} </div>
    <div> {{$DataSet[$i]->number}} </div>
</div>
@endfor

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#datepicker').on('change', function() {
     var datepicker = $('#datepicker').val();
     alert(datepicker);

     $.ajax({
            url: '/orderdata',
            data: datepicker,
            type: "get",
            cache: false,
            success: function () {
                $('#something').empty();
                $('#something').append();
            },
            error: function () {
                ;}});});
</script>
```

Route

```
Route::get('/orderdata', 'DayhomeController@OrderDataorIndex');
```

1.I would like to ask if I use ajax to pass the datepicker value to the controller, should I pass it to the index or create another public function OrderData($Request $datepickerVal){} ? because I need to use the value of the datepicker as a condition to retrieve the modal update Dataset[i] again.

2.The data enters function index or function OrderData, and finally returns a new dataset[], will this help me refresh the page, or should I do something like $('#something').empty $('#something').append() in ajax success:function  to update my object and its {{$DataSet[$i]->name}} {{$DataSet[$i]->number}} number?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 3 ways to accomplish this

### Page reload

Reload the page and send query string in the url eg: `"/yourpath?date=" + $date`, then in your controller:

```js
window.location.href = 'https://your.url/path?date=' + $('#datepicker').val();
```

```php
class DayhomeController extend Controller{
public function index(){
 $Dataset = Modal::all();
  if(request()->get('date')){
    $Dataset = $Dataset->where('date',request()->get('date'))
  }
 return view('DayHome')->with('DataSet',$DataSet)
}
```

#### Ajax return HTML

you could make a controller+page/view that only returns the HTML of your rendered data set.

then you can call this route/controller and just replace the html with jQuery:

```
 $.ajax({
            url: '/orderdata',
            data: datepicker,
            type: "get",
            cache: false,
            success: function (htmlReceived) {
                $('#something').html(htmlReceived);

            },
       });})
```

#### Ajax + javascript rendiner library

you could also always get the Data set via ajax and instead create your render method locally using, react, alpineJS, svelte, vue or any other frontend rendering library or framework

*** This code does not follow best practises but tries to explain your problem

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, they are very specific and also solved my problem here.